# Drupal Dropdown Menu

Tags: css, drupal, drop-down-menu

I am having trouble with my drop down menus. I would like to have multiple columns under one drop down.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ru3Zv/ here is what I am working with.

```
 #navigation-primary > ul > li > h2, #navigation-primary > ul > li > a {
/* font-size of the first level */
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 40px;
}
#navigation-primary > ul > li > h2 > a, #navigation-primary > ul > li > a {
/* links of the first level */
/* text-transform: uppercase; */
color:white;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration:none;
/* background: #156aa3; */
background: #1f1f1f;
}
#navigation-primary > ul > li > a.active, #navigation-primary > ul > li > h2 > a.active {
/* active state of the first level */
background:#1f1f1f;
color:#fff;
}
#navigation-primary > ul > li > a:hover, #navigation-primary > ul > li > h2 > a:hover, #navigation-primary > ul > li:hover > a, #navigation-primary > ul > li:hover > h2 > a {
/* hover state of the first level */
background:#1f1f1f;
color:#fff;
}
#navigation-primary .mega a {
/* links color inside panel */
color:white;
}
#navigation-primary .mega a:hover {
/* :hover on links inside panel */
color:white;
/* text-decoration:underline; */
font-size:1.10em
}
#navigation-primary .mega ul.megamenu-2 a {
/* color:#4c4b4b;*/
/* This is the color of the submenu items */
color:#ffffff;
}
#navigation-primary h3, #navigation-primary li.menu-section-title > a {
/* primary links subsection titles */
font-size:1.0em;
/* text-transform:uppercase; */
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration:none
}
#navigation-primary li.menu-leaf-list {
/* child links inside the panel */
/* border-bottom: 1px dashed #e2e2e2;*/
}
.mega {
/* border-top: 10px solid #1f1f1f; */
border-bottom: 4px solid #1f1f1f;
border-left:1px solid #1f1f1f;
/* border-right:1px solid #ccc; */
background:#1f1f1f;
white-space:nowrap !important;
width:auto !important;
}
```

Under the Services menu I would like to have one column with Managed Services then the underlined links below that then in a second column have Consulting Services with the rest of the underlined links below that. This is similar to http://www.workday.com/.

What would I have to change to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this module. It might help.

https://drupal.org/project/megamenu

example:

http://www.aaml.org/

Answer (score 0):

For the multiple columns under one drop down use "tb mega menu". Only for drupal 7.
https://drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu